# Use of undeclared type 'MessagingDelegate'

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4, xcode9

I have implemented FCM successfully. Now I wanted to send the Notification on device. I was fooilowing tutorial given on FCM console themselves.

For this I moved forward in ther tutorial but found errors as shown in picture below ...

[image]

I do not know why I am getting this error. However as I wanted to remove that error but fails. I do not know why they are coming. `i even copy paster their own example project app delegate methods. But still I am getting those error which I showed in picture.

I have imported following thing

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
```

**here is my pod file**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyProject
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

What is problem please rectify

Comment: Did you import Firebase?

Comment: @mag_zbc yes i did import that

Comment: Did yo add the firebase via pod? if so please show that podfile.

Comment: yes I did, let me update the question

Comment: @SharadChauhan question updated with pod file

Comment: checkout the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to update the pod file;

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

Comment: but on console from where I am following this tutorial they have not mentioned this thing

Comment: @Androidteem yes you are right. when I was doing it, had same issue and after some research came to know that we'll need to add that messaging module too

Comment: Note that the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#add_the_sdk) does tell you that you must include the Messaging pod

Comment: I have both in my podfile, but I still get the error. After I did pop update.

Comment: Yes I had to change the type to FIBMessaging, then it worked